# Keeping text attributes in an array

Tags: php, arrays, text, attributes

I have been using this fairly simple PHP to create a menu with names of shops. Due to the fact that my customer is now now expanding to different markets, he wants specific lines in the array to be bold. Everything I have tried has been a failure, does anyone have any suggestions? I am currently using a .txt, as you see, is there a format that would be better for this?

```
<td>
    <!--<li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_4">-->
    <label class="formFieldQuestion">Supervisor</label><select class="mainForm" style="width: 100%" name="field_4" id="field_4">
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option><?php $shops = file('SHOPS.txt');
    foreach($shops as $line){
        echo '<option value=\'';
        echo $line;
        echo '\'>';
        echo $line;
        echo '</option>';
    }
    ?></select>
</td>
```

Comment: How can you tell which lines are supposed to be bold? Are they marked in the text file?

Comment: Do those specific lines have any special difference with the rest of lines? If no, can the text file be modified so those specific line for example start with  some special characters specifying they should be bold?

Comment: Can an option be bolded?

Comment: That is really my question there is no way to make just one line bold in a .txt file that i know of, it won't read the HTML <b> tag, i'm looking for any advice on what type file i should use besides a .txt file or any other way to do this besides adding the full list into the code

Comment: Or if there is a way to make it recognize <b></b> maybe?

Comment: @Samuri do you know of any character that could specify it, what i've done so far is save the txt file as UTF-8 encoding so symbols will show up in the array, that way it can display ** before the specific lines